# Check that file is not being written to before moving to in shell script

Tags: unix

I need to write an Unix Shell Script tran.sh that moves the csv input files from `/exp/files` folder to `/exp/ready` directory. The csv input files are written to `/exp/files` folder by an SFTP server whose behavior I cannot trivially change.

In tran.sh shell script I need to ensure before doing a move of that csv input file from /exp/files directory no longer any other process is writing to the file. How can I move it?

Answer (score 3):

`lsof` might be what you want (it is after all, the command to `list open files`). If your files have a known naming convention, run an `lsof <filename>` against it to check if it is indeed being used by a process. If it isn't, `lsof` will return a non-zero return code.

Comment: Please note: If you want to check if the file is being written to by another user, you'll need to run `lsof` (or `fuser`) as `root`. If you're checking a file on NFS, `lsof` or `fuser` will only tell you something when run on the machine from which the file is being written to.