# Check if Files are Being Written To

Tags: linux, shell, prompt

*Note: I've read the [other question](https://superuser.com/q/447449/114557), but I need it differently.*

I'm working on my NAS, which also works as a storing device for my PVR. Now I want to change my shell prompt on the NAS whenever the PVR is writing a broadcast to it (consider it a "don't do anything long-lasting while a broadcast is being recorded"-warning). My first idea was to prefix the prompt with a red `REC`.

As pointed out in the other question I can use `lsof` for this:

```
# lsof /broadcast/storage/path/broadcast.ts; echo $?
<output of lsof>
0
# lsof /broadcast/storage/path/doesnt-exist.ts; echo $?
1
#
```

However, `lsof` doesn't seem to work for me if I use

```
# lsof /broadcast/storage/path/*; echo $?
<output of lsof>
1
#
```

The logic seems to be that it returns 1 when it finds a file that is not in use. However, for me it should return 0 when at least one file is in use.

I know that I can loop over the files and stop when the first file returns 0, but since I want to have this in the prompt I don't know how to make this a one-liner.

EDIT:
Thanks to tink I reworked my idea and my prompt now looks like this (note that I had to make the wildcard work as `lsof /.../*` would be globbed into PS1 already):

```
export PS1='`find /broacast/storage/path/ -name "*.sc" -print0 | \
    xargs -0 lsof | \
    grep -q COMMAND && echo -e "\033[0;31m[REC]-\033[0;37m"`\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, why don't you just:

```
lsof /broacast/storage/path/* | grep -q broadcast/storage/path ; echo $?
```

Comment: That takes way too long to be used in a prompt.

Comment: I see. How about a double-whammy?  I edited the original answer to match what I suggested.

Comment: Oh, good idea. See my edit in the question.